# How to import database into Navicat Lite or sqlitemanager in Titanium

Tags: sqlite, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

In my titanium application I can able to create the database and access it.But I don't know how to import my database in into Query Browsers like Navicat Lite or sqlitemanager extension on Firefox.

I am working on Android Platform. My Titanium SDK verison is 1.7.5 Operating System : ubuntu
how do I import my database into Navicat Lite?

Comment: sqlitemanager has the option of import in Databas tab in the top bar.

Comment: @muhammad My question is how do I found database path(location of the sqllite database)?. I am creating database using following command var db = Titanium.Database.open('demodb');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your database file,

Go to the folder where your android SDK is placed. In your android SDK there is a folder named tools. open that folder. In the tools folder you can find a tool named DDMS. Open that DDMS tool.

In DDMS open the device menu and select file explorer. Now you will have a new window which contains all the files of your currently opened EMULATOR. Now your database file path of your app will be ,

data/data/your application id(com.org.etc etc)/databases/dbfilename.db

export this DB file from DDMS to your local directory like desktop or any where you want. than you can open that file in your sqlitemanager.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, Titanium places the SQLite DB in /Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/ ... then there's a GUID/Library/Application Support/database/my sqlite db

My sense is that, for Droids, there would be a similar simulator folder created.

Also, I believe that in Titanium Studio, you can locate the app support path for the DB with Ti.Filesystem.applicationSupportDirectory (perhaps just alert this value ... have not tried that but should work in theory!).